# How can I decode a ISO-8859-1 encoded string in JavaScript or Swift?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm currently developing an iOS app and I have a string encoded in ISO-8859-1 format: £2,970.98 (it's showing the pound symbol here but its actually: & # 1 6 3 ;). I'm trying to decode this string back to its original form using either JavaScript or Swift.

I've got a WKWebView in my app, so that's how I can run JavaScript code within the app if necessary.
So I've tried using the `decodeURIComponent` function and other things in swift and in JavaScript, but it doesn't seem to work for ISO-8859-1 encoded strings.
Are there any other options for decoding this type of string in either JavaScript or Swift? Thank you!

Note that it doesn't auto translate it to a pound symbol in my app:

[image]

Comment: The use of `&#xxx;` represents an HTML entity and is not related the string encoding.

Comment: I just tried that and it works! Thank you so much :)